# Hilbert Matrix and Approximation Theory

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

I was reading about the [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) and [Cauchy determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix):

\[  \det \left[ \frac{1}{i+j-1} \right]_{i,j} \]

By guessing where this determinant is $0$ or $\infty$ we can guess the right formula.  In Wikipedia, I found this problem:

> "Assume that $I = [a, b]$ is a real interval. Is it then possible to find a non-zero 
>   polynomial $P$ with integral coefficients, such that the integral $\int_a^b P(x)^2\, dx$
>   is smaller than any given bound $\varepsilon > 0$, taken arbitrarily small?"
>
> To answer this question, Hilbert derives an exact formula for the determinant of the 
>   Hilbert matrices and investigates their asymptotics. He concludes that the answer to his 
>   question is positive if the length $b − a$ of the interval is smaller than $4$.

I'm asking for a reference / proof to this exercise.  I think you can expand $P$ in [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), or use the [Gram determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).

In general, why is this matrix related to approximation theory?

Comment: This matrix (with $i,j$ ranging over $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \ldots, d \rbrace$)
arises naturally in such problems because it is the Gram matrix of
the basis $(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^d)$ of the space of
polynomials of degree at most $d$ with respect to the inner product
$\langle P,Q \rangle = \int_0^1 P(x) Q(x) dx$.


Comment: I believe that the answer to your question lies in the paper by Hilbert which you can find on the wikipedia page on Hilber matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In the generically titled, [Ein Beitrag zur Theorie des Legendre'schen Polynoms](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%252FBF02418278?LI=true) Hilbert says integral  $\int_a^b P(x)^2 dx $ defines quaratic form over the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

Over $[0,1]$ the determinant in the basis $\{ 1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n \}$ is:

\[  D_{[a,b]} = \int_{[a,b]^n} x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\dots x_{n-2}^2 x_{n-1} \prod_{i < j}(x_i - x_j)^2 d\mathbf{x} = \left( \frac{b-a}{2} \right)^{n^2} D \]

Usually Legendre polynomials are defined over [0,1], but you can do a change of variables.  In that basis the quadratic form is diagonalized:

\[ \int_a^b P(x)^2 \, dx = \frac{2}{2n-1}b_1^2 + \frac{2}{2n-3} b_2^2 + \dots ,  \]

where we expand in Legendre polynomials $P(x) = b_1 p_1(x) + b_2 p_2(x) + \dots . $ You are finding the determinant of this change of variables:

\[ \left| \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & \frac{1}{n} \\\\ 
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\\\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\\\
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \dots  & \frac{1}{2n+1}
\end{array}\right| = \frac{\left[1^{n-1}2^{n-2}\dots (n-2)^2(n-1)\right]^4}{1^{2n-1}2^{2n-2}\dots (2n-2)^2(2n-1)} .\]

The discriminant of this quadratic form to be proportional to $ \left(\frac{b-a}{4}\right)^n$ which tends to 0 for $b-a < 4$.

Polynomials with integer coefficients form an lattice in the space of polynomials.  For this discriminant to tend to 0, there must be polynomials with arbitrarily small norm.

---

I still find this result counterintuitive... We can find explicit examples, when $|a|,|b|<1$

\[  \int_{a}^b x^{2n} \, dx = \frac{b^{2n+1}-a^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \]

but not sure about $a=0,b=2$, for example.

Comment: Trying to make the result more intuitive: Recall that the Chebyshev polynomials $T_n$ defined by $T_n(2 \cos x) = 2 \cos(nx)$ take $[-2,2]$ to $[-2,2]$ and have integer coefficients, so $\int_{x=-2}^2 T_n(x)^2 dx \leq \int_{x=-2}^2 4 dx  = 16$. So, for $[a,b]=[-2,2]$, we can make the integral constant independent of $n$, and it isn't surprising (but still needs proof) that for $b-a <4$ we can do better.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Do you think [Chebyshev polynoimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) are a better choice than [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) that Hilbert picked?  In Legendre basis this is a rational quadratic form so it can take arbitrarily small values as $n \to \infty$, I guess.

Comment: Legnedre's give the optimal answer; Chebyshev makes it obvious to me that $b-a=4$ should be the cut off.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Legendre polynomials also arise as the matrix elements of [$SO(3)$ representations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52071/what-is-the-physical-meaning-concept-behind-legendre-polynomials). I got interested because of Hilbert's use of [Minkowski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_theorem) and geometry of numbers, but never collected my thoughts on this.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I got started reading on this since I didn't realize that just because $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ doesn't mean $\int_0^x P(s)^2 ds \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  So this is a rational quadratic form in the coefficients of $P(x)$.